# Where should I add AppSpec.yml file in CodeDeploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I am deploying code from Amazon S3 to EC2 instance with codeDeploy.I have configured the the configuration group and application but I am getting this error
 `The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.`

When I check the logs I see

"The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at revision-relative path \\"appspec.yml\\"

What exactly is a appspec.yml file and where should I place it? i am new to AWS so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you need should be present : [Amazon documentation Appspec File.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html)

> File location
>
> To verify that you have placed your AppSpec file in the root directory
>   of the application's source content's directory structure

[Add an Application Specification File to a Revision for CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/application-revisions-appspec-file.html)

> Add an AppSpec File for an AWS Lambda Deployment For a deployment to
>   an AWS Lambda compute platform:
>
> The AppSpec file contains instructions about the Lambda functions to
>   be deployed and used for deployment validation.
>
> A revision is the same as an AppSpec file.
>
> An AppSpec file can be written using JSON or YAML.
>
> An AppSpec file can be saved as a text file or entered directly into a
>   console AppSpec editor when creating a deployment. For more
>   information, see Create an AWS Lambda Compute Platform Deployment
>   (Console).
>
> To create an AppSpec file:
>
> Copy the JSON or YAML template into a text editor or into the AppSpec
>   editor in the console.
>
> Modify the template as needed.
>
> Use a JSON or YAML validator to validate your AppSpec file. If you use
>   the AppSpec editor, the file is validated when you choose Create
>   deployment.
>
> If you use a text editor, save the file. If you use the AWS CLI to
>   create your deployment, reference the AppSpec file if it's on your
>   hard drive or in an Amazon S3 bucket. If you use the console, you must
>   push your AppSpec file to Amazon S3.

Add an AppSpec File for an EC2/On-Premises Deployment

> To add an AppSpec file to a revision:
>
> Copy the template into a text editor.
>
> Modify the template as needed.
>
> Use a YAML validator to check the validity of your AppSpec file.
>
> Save the file as appspec.yml in the root directory of the revision.
>
> Run one of the following commands to verify that you have placed your
>   AppSpec file in the root directory:
>
> For Linux, macOS, or Unix:
>
> `find /path/to/root/directory -name appspec.yml` There will be no output
>   if the AppSpec file is not found there.
>
> For Windows:
>
> `dir path\to\root\directory\appspec.yml` A File Not Found error will be
>   displayed if the AppSpec file is not stored there.
>
> Push the revision to Amazon S3 or GitHub.

Comment: Appspec.yml should be contained in the zip folder or Is there any other way I could place it in codedeploy?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/application-revisions-appspec-file.html
Apparently all your questions are in the documentation.

Comment: @daveMiller : this is not the answer you expected? did it help you?

Comment: it did help me.Thanks

Comment: I have deployed code on my ec2 instance now is there any way I could run tests on that code?

Comment: I don't know, I never did what you are doing :) I just read the documentation :) You should ask another question or read the documentation :)